# cryptsetup: Cannot wipe header on device

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I am trying to encrypt an external hard drive on Ubuntu 14.04 followig [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/). I started by formatting to *ext4*:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sde1
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
9773056 inodes, 39072470 blocks
1953623 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
1193 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

And then proceeded with the initialisation, but it returns this error:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/sde1

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/sde1 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase: 
Verify passphrase: 
Cannot wipe header on device /dev/sde1.
Command failed with code 5: Cannot wipe header on device /dev/sde1.
```

So far I could not anything useful on the web regarding this error. Any ideas on what may be wrong?

**Update I**: answering [the questions posed by Xen2050](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706585/cryptsetup-cannot-wipe-header-on-device?noredirect=1#comment1038080_706585). I ran `bablocks` in write mode prior to formatting and no errors were reported.

I tried the ecryption again, paying more attention to systems messages. Here is the `dmesg` output right after connecting the drive:

```
$ dmesg
[ 3208.032228] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3208.140990] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=0651
[ 3208.141001] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3208.141024] usb 2-1.4: Product: LaCie Hard Drive USB
[ 3208.141031] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: LaCie
[ 3208.141037] usb 2-1.4: SerialNumber: 10000E000BD8A671
[ 3208.177576] usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3208.178112] scsi4 : usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0
[ 3208.178183] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 3209.176917] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SEAGATE  ST3160812A       3.AA PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 3209.177561] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 3209.181342] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 312581808 512-byte logical blocks: (160 GB/149 GiB)
[ 3209.182337] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3209.182348] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[ 3209.183339] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 3209.201618]  sdb: sdb1
[ 3209.229465] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Then verified it is not mounted:

```
$ findmnt /dev/sdb
$ findmnt /dev/sdb1
$
```

Another try at initialisation:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/sdb1

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/sdb1 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase: 
Verify passphrase: 
Cannot wipe header on device /dev/sdb1.
Command failed with code 5: Cannot wipe header on device /dev/sdb1.
```

Two new lines show up in the log:

```
$ tail /var/log/syslog
Dec  8 09:18:20 MekanikDestruktiwKommandoh kernel: [ 3698.016311] end_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
Dec  8 09:18:28 MekanikDestruktiwKommandoh wpa_supplicant[1188]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
```

Something seems going wrong with sector 0, but not at all clear what.

**Update II**: Trying the [new suggestions by Xen2050](https://askubuntu.com/a/707304/177437). First writing zeros to sector 0:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M count=10
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.564427 s, 18.6 MB/s
```

After this the `cryptsetup` initialisation still fails. `wipefs` returns a strange warning:

```
$ sudo wipefs -a /dev/sdb
wipefs: WARNING: /dev/sdb: appears to contain 'dos' partition table
```

And apparently does nothing. Then ran `cryptsetup` with the `debug` flag; it printed out a bunch of new stuff, but does not give more information regarding the error:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup --debug -y -v luksFormat /dev/sdb
# cryptsetup 1.6.1 processing "cryptsetup --debug -y -v luksFormat /dev/sdb"
# Running command luksFormat.
# Locking memory.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/sdb irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
# Allocating crypt device /dev/sdb context.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sdb.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Timeout set to 0 miliseconds.
# Iteration time set to 1000 miliseconds.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
Enter passphrase: 
Verify passphrase: 
# Formatting device /dev/sdb as type LUKS1.
# Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.5.3) initialized.
# Topology: IO (512/0), offset = 0; Required alignment is 1048576 bytes.
# Generating LUKS header version 1 using hash sha1, aes, xts-plain64, MK 32 bytes
# Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.5.3) initialized.
# KDF pbkdf2, hash sha1: 356173 iterations per second.
# Data offset 4096, UUID 5fa9c58f-b047-4c9e-a6e8-26a9a433a438, digest iterations 43375
Cannot wipe header on device /dev/sdb.
# Releasing crypt device /dev/sdb context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Unlocking memory.
Command failed with code 5: Cannot wipe header on device /dev/sdb.
```

Comment: That's an onion in the ointment... any more descriptive messages in /var/log/syslog? `/dev/sde1` isn't mounted while trying to luksFormat it? Maybe cryptsetup doesn't want to overwrite a mounted in-use partition... And it's still a "healthy" writeable drive? And the format to ext4 step should be *after* the luksFormat, but I think cryptsetup should be able to overwrite anything anyway, so that shouldn't stop it...

Comment: How strange, badblocks writes ok, mkfs.ext4 writes ok, but cryptsetup fails trying to write to sector 0... maybe a cryptsetup bug, I wonder if sdb1 contains a sector 0, or if it's trying to write to the very start of sdb (actually I'm not sure if drives start at sector 1 or 0, writing to a non-existing sector sounds like a critical error...) (No access to a regular browser now or I'd google that sector 0 error + cryptsetup)

Answer (score 4):

I'm aware that this question is very old, but I was looking for a solution for the same error message, "Cannot wipe header on device", and found a solution that is not listed here: if the `cryptsetup luksFormat` output also includes the following:

> WARNING: Data offset is outside of currently available data device.

then the **partition is too small.**

You're most likely to run into this if you are creating a partition that is meant to just contain a key file to encrypt other partitions.

It appears that with `cryptsetup` 2.1.0, the LUKS header takes up just under 16MiB (see below for details), so the partition size must **16MiB + the size of the key** you want to store in it (3MiB, say).

For illustration, with an 8MiB partition, I saw the following error:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksFormat ${/dev/keypartition} --debug
[...]
# Formatting LUKS2 with JSON metadata area 12288 bytes and keyslots area 16744448 bytes.
[...]
WARNING: Data offset is outside of currently available data device.
Device wipe error, offset 8388608.
Cannot wipe header on device /dev/sda2.
```

Note that 12288 bytes + 16744448 bytes = 15.98 MiB.

With the size of `/dev/sda2` increased to 19MiB, I successfully set it up as a LUKS partition.

**Note:** `cryptsetup luksFormat` also worked with `dev/sda2` at 16MiB, but a subsequent `cryptsetup luksOpen` failed with

> Requested offset is beyond real size of device /dev/sda2.

Increasing `/dev/sda2` further to 32MiB fixed this issue, but when I tried to use the partition as a key file, `cryptsetup luksFormat --key-file=/dev/mapper/<mountpoint of /dev/sda2> <device to encrypt>` failed with

> Maximum keyfile size exceeded.

There are two solutions to this: (1) set the size of the partition containing to key to 16MiB + key file size ensuring that the key file size is less than the maximum; (2) use the `--keyfile-size` option so `cryptsetup luksFormat` only uses some part of the key file.

Answer (score 3):

One fellow solved this (or very similar) error by manually writing zeros to the first few megs of the target partition with a line similar to this:

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=[target] bs=1M count=2
```

Or if it's just an overwriting FS problem, then `wipefs` might work instead of / with the above.

Also, another used the "--debug" option with `cryptsetu`p to get more information, it's worth a try first.

---

The "Update II" info tests use /dev/sdb1 and then /dev/sdb, not sure it would make a difference though.

[Another guy here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1170086) says *"I've had floppies, thumb drives and hard drives have 'sector 0' issues that were all fixed by going into a Linux Live CD and wiping the first hundred sectors or so with* `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hdN bs=1024 count=1024` "

[This bug report comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1368299/comments/15) about another external USB hard drive and a "*end_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0*" seems to say Ubuntu 12.04 worked while 14.04 didn't. [Others say](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156380/why-is-my-external-usb-hard-drive-sometimes-completely-inaccessible) it's probably a bad or inadequate USB power supply or failing hardware (enclosure, wires, hard drive)

So mixed results & advice. I've not had the best luck with USB enclosures either, I'd be inclined to try a different enclosure or a direct to desktop/esata cable connection.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a very similar error message as recently as 2022 with 20.04.4 LTS when trying to `cryptsetup` a partition on a ~1TB external SSD:

```
Device wipe error, offset 0.
Cannot wipe header on device /dev/sda2.
```

Bizarrely enough, simply unplugging a bunch of USB devices (everything except keyboard / mouse / the external SSD) made the error go away.

Comment: Insufficient USB power seems to do this.  I had a drive go offline under write load (2.5" HDD) on a liberated Chromebook.  Too bad cryptsetup doesn't report that the lower layer disappeared - the error message becomes confusing requiring a dmesg scan to figure it out.